# How is System.IsLibrary different from SysInit.ModuleIsLib?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

There are `System.IsLibrary`

> Indicates whether the module is a shared library.
>
> The IsLibrary variable is True if the module is a dynamic link library (DLL).

and `SysInit.ModuleIsLib`

> Is True if this module is a DLL (a dynamic-link library or a package).

What is the difference between the two?

Does anything change for C++ Builder?

Comment: Hard to know from sure, but if I'm reading the RTL sources correctly, `IsLibrary` is true for a DLL but not for a BPL, whereas `ModuleIsLib` is True for both. But I didn't test this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it has something to do with app using run-time packages. I believe SysInit is a special unit.

Answer (score 2):

**System.IsLibrary** is set during the initialisation of the RTL.  If the RTL is initialised as part of a loaded EXE (the RTL may well of course have been linked as a package) then `System.IsLibrary` is false, otherwise it is true.  (See below for how this can be overridden, although the effective meaning remains unchanged.)

So if you have written an RTL based App (in Delphi or C++ Builder) you will see that `System.IsLibrary` is always False, even if you call it from a package that you have subsequently loaded dynamically.

If you have written a library (DLL / Dylib / SO) that's a library and not a package then it will not share the RTL with the application it's loaded into, and it can be loaded into an application that is not RTL based.  As it has it's own RTL, when the RTL is intialised it will set `System.IsLibrary` to True.

If you load a package dynamically using `LoadPackage` it does not reinitialise the RTL, and so the value of `System.IsLibrary` remains unchanged.

**SysInit.ModuleIsLib** is part of the `SysInit` unit which is, as @Александр Кулагин says, a special unit that is linked into every executable and library.  The values of the variables in `SysInit` are controlled by the compiler, so it records how the code was built.  The relevant variables are set when `VCLInit` is called like this:

`SysInit.ModuleIsLib` is true if the code was built as part of a library (including a package).

`SysInit.ModuleIsPackage` is true if the code was built as part of a package (so for a library that's not a package this will be false.)

As part of `SysInit.VCLInit` `System.IsLibrary` is set to true if the code was built as a library but not as a package, otherwise it is unchanged.  If the code was built as a library but not a package, then it's expected that it will be using its own RTL.

As it is the same code that's included when building with C++Builder there is no change when using C++ Builder to build code.

Answer (score 1):

I think, one should not use `System.IsLibrary`.

If our application uses DLLs, and all its modules (EXE and DLLs) are written in Delphi and compiled with runtime packages, then all variables of `System` unit reside in the same place: in `rtl???.bpl`. This bpl is loaded into process in a single copy, therefore there is a single copy of `System.IsLibrary` for EXE and all DLLs.

On the other hand, `SysInit` unit is linked separately with each module. So every module has its own independent copy of `SysInit.ModuleIsLib` variable.

Of course, if some module is compiled without runtime packages, it WILL have its own independent copy of `System.IsLibrary`, and this variable MAY have correct value. But I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: Whether or not you should use `System.IsLibrary` is not the issue.  The issue is understanding what it's telling you and using it appropriately.  It does not tell you whether the code you are currently executing is part of the main executable or a package.  If you want to know that you can use `(Module.Instance=MainInstance)` which will be true if the current code was loaded as part of the executable code, and false if it was loaded from a package.